# I can not alter my my serializer before saving it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I can not alter my my serializer before saving it

at first try modifying the method def perform_create but the error was this

using this code

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    key = self.request.META.get('HTTP_APIKEY', b'')
    store_obj = StoreApiKey.objects.get(key=key)
    serializer.save(store=store_obj.store)
```

but got that.

`Got a`TypeError`when calling` Order.objects.create () `. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to`Order.objects.create ()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the CreateOrderSerializer.create () method to handle this correctly.`

then try to modify the serializer method

```
def create (self, validated_data):
    validated_data ['store'] = self.context ['store']
    super (CreateOrderSerializer, self) .create (validated_data)
```

but this tells me

Field name `customer_number` is not valid for model`Order`.

Do you have any ideas that you can give me? I will place my code here

```
class OrderAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (ApiKeyAuth,)
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateOrderSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        # queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        # key = self.request.META.get('HTTP_APIKEY', b'')
        # store_obj = StoreApiKey.objects.get(key=key)
        # filter_kwargs = {'store': store_obj}
        # obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)

        serializer = ListOrderSerializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        key = self.request.META.get('HTTP_APIKEY', b'')
        store_obj = StoreApiKey.objects.get(key=key)
        serializer.save(store=store_obj.store)

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        ctx = super().get_serializer_context()

        key = self.request.META.get('HTTP_APIKEY', b'')
        store_obj = StoreApiKey.objects.get(key=key)

        ctx['store'] = store_obj.store

        return ctx

class CreateOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    store = serializers.HiddenField(default="")

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ("customer_name", "customer_email", "customer_number", 
     "store")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['store'] = self.context['store']
        print("*/**************************************************")
        return super(CreateOrderSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

   class Order(models.Model):

    number = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Number',
        default=get_random_string(length=5),
        max_length=5,
        editable=False
    )

    store = models.ForeignKey(
        Store,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Date',
        default=datetime.date.today
    )

    picked = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name='Picked',
        default=False
    )

    delivered = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name='Delivered',
        default=False
    )

    # customer info

    customer_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Customer name',
        max_length=100
    )

    customer_email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Customer email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    customer_phone = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Customer phone number',
        max_length=15,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default=''
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Order'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Orders'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number

    def get_authors(self):
        return ', '.join(
            self.authors.all().values_list('item', flat=True)
        )
```

Comment: You don't have a `customer` number in your model. I suspect you wanted to write `number`. Edit your serializer's fields to use the correct name.

As for the store, you only need to pass it to the save method, no need to add it to context. Or you can use context and leave out the save method. Also post the json data you're using to test

Comment: I understood what you tried to tell me, I'm going to try but, maybe this does not explain it, the store comes for a header that is really a token and through the store and it's what I want to pass to save that's why you see it in the context

Comment: I am not completely sure yet but the error is most likely due to the `customer_number`. The model manager's create method expects only fields of the model to be passed as keyword arguments but it is getting `customer_number` which is not a field in the model. In any case, correct that error and let me know if it works